# How to describe extracted values to an array in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code, I cannot describe the [group, items]: Mapped using interface unless I use any idea how to describe such scenario? the mapped interface shows exactly how the arguments of the map should look like yet it still refuses to work is it the wrapping array that causing this?

```js
interface Mapped {
  group: string;
  items: { item: string}[];
  }

const items =// obje

return (
<Container>
  {Object.entries(items)).map(([group, items]: Mapped, i) => (
    <div>
      {/* <ul>{Icons[group]}</ul> */}
      {items.map((itmes: any) => (
      item.item
        />
      ))}
    </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't fully map to your interface it does allow you to iterate the object (it does also assume that group is unique per item).

```js
interface Mapped {
      group: string;
      items: { item: string}[];
      }

    const items: any = {"group1": {items: [{item: "1"}, {item: "2"}]}, "group2": {items: [{item: "1"}, {item: "2"}]}}

    return (
    <Container>
      {Object.keys(items).forEach((grp: string) => {
        <div>
          {/* <ul>{Icons[grp]}</ul> */}
          items[grp].items.map((item: { item: string}) => 
            <span>{item}</span>
          )
        </div>
      }}
    </Container>
```

If you're more interested in getting the structure you could try:

```js
{Object.entries(items).map((grpItem: any) =>  {
      let t: Mapped = {group: grpItem[0], items: grpItem[1]};
      ...
  })
}
```